# DevTools was disconnected from the page(when creating and retrieve node with text content)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

1. I create a simple node: `let sp = document.createElement('SPAN');`
2. Then I include some text in it: `sp.innerText = 'some text here';`
3. Try to output created element to the console: `sp` (just type its name in the console)

But when I try to output this element to the console I get a message:
**DevTools was disconnected from the page. Once page is reloaded, DevTools will automatically reconnect.**

Developer environment:

- *about:blank* page
- Google Chrome Version 74.0.3729.131 (Official build), (64 bit)

[image: DevTools message]

**Updated**:

Even with `console.log(sp)` I get this DevTools message.

There is no such message if I output with `dir(sp)`.

**Updated 26.05.2019**:
This happens if I create any element, not only `span`

[image: DevTools message]

**Updated 05.06.2019**:
The problem is gone after updating Google Chrome to version `75.0.3770.80`

Comment: What is the step number 3 "output the element to the console"?

Comment: @Esko the third step probably is just entering `sp` in the console and pressing return.

Comment: @PranavTotla Might be or it might not be, it should be included in the question.

Comment: @Esko just enter in console `sp` to see the result, but get an error message

Comment: @PranavTotla exactly

Comment: Does it happen on pages other than `about:blank`?

Comment: On any page @KayceBasques, not only on `about:blank`

Comment: @RinatValiullov Consider accepting Zhou TK's answer since this is what solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

update to 75.0.3770.80 and the problem solved